# Kotlin Multiplatform project building keeps failing after adding dependencies

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, jetbrains-compose

I created a Kotlin Multiplatform project (for the web).
After adding a dependency (in my case `io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.1.1`) the building of the project fails. I get following exception:

```
e: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sequence has more than one element.
    at kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt.single(_Sequences.kt:335)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.JsIntrinsics.<init>(JsIntrinsics.kt:198)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.JsIrBackendContext.<init>(JsIrBackendContext.kt:180)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.JsIrBackendContext.<init>(JsIrBackendContext.kt:49)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.CompilerKt.compile(compiler.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.backend.js.CompilerKt.compile$default(compiler.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JsIrCompiler.doExecute(K2JsIrCompiler.kt:328)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.js.K2JSCompiler.doExecute(K2JSCompiler.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1618)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            testTask {
                testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                    useFirefox()
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.web.core)
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.1.1")
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you trying the `-js` variant of the dependency? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#set-a-dependency-on-a-kotlinx-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 1.6.10 — https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52047.
Workaround is to use 1.7.10 and 1.2.0-beta02 Compose.